# Get viewPager reference from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an MainActivity.java, On this Activity There is a fragment (SwipeFragment) that contains ViewPager and on this viewPager I am using another fragment (ImageViewFragment) that contains ImageView. 
I just want to get that viewPager reference in ImageViewFragment.

When I just use Activity with viewPager and Fragment with ImageView then it was enough easy to get viewPager reference with getActivity() method to get activity firstly then viewpager with this reference in ImageVIewFragment. 
But With fragment i didn't find any method.

If anyone know that help me, thanks in advance

Comment: So basically you have nested fragments, right?

Comment: Yeah! you can say

Comment: I've asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379050/parent-fragment-to-child-fragment-communication) a while ago, tell me if it helps you.

Comment: I don't know if you got your answer but here it is anyway.  Try this:   MainActivity mActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity(); -> mActivity.getViewpager().

Answer (score 0):

**In Adapter class from where parent Fragment initiates**

```
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mFragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.addToBackStack("ParentFragment");


        ParentFragment parentFragment=new ParentFragment();

        ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, parentFragment,"ParentFragment");
        ft.commit();
```

**Now in Child Fragment to get reference of Parent Fragment**

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();  //worked somehow, now testing with viewPager reference
    ParentFragment parentFragment= (ParentFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ParentFragment");
```

Comment: You don't have to go through all this trouble, there is a method `getParentFragment()`, it's explained in one of the answers that I sent you.